# Function definition for 'XYZ' not found

Tags: c, visual-studio-2022

I have a Visual Studio 2022 project which includes various functions from a statically linked library. I include the libraries header file, which has the functions in it, for example:

```
bool XYZ(const unsigned char* data);
```

The project compiles and runs absolutely fine, but the IDE keeps warning me that `Function definition for 'XYZ' not found.` underlining `XYZ` with green squiggles.

My question is; how do I get VS to correctly understand that these functions are available in the static library that I am including, and therefore silence this warning? or is this an issue with VS that I just have to live with?

I've tried changing the function declartion to start with `extern`, but that made no difference.

I've also tried searching for this warning message but all the results seem to relate to linker errors rather than a IDE warning that I get.

Comment: Yes, the header files are included using `#include`, all methods in the the header are highlighted in the IDE with the same green squiggle warning. Yet the application compiles absolutely fine, and the methods are being used with no issue.

Comment: If you figure it out let me know. Not like I could do it better, but Intellisense is a far cry from what's advertised IMO, at least for my project that uses CMake and external clang formatting. I live in a world of red underline squigglies even tho things compile and run just fine.

Comment: It sounds like you are doing something wrong. I suggest you create the smallest possible program that calls a function in the library (it doesn't even have to run, you just want to see if it gives the same compiler warning).  If the small program has the same compiler warning, then post the program here so we can see what you are doing. By the way, if you rest the cursor over the green squiggle I believe the IDE will tell you why the green squiggle is there. We need that info.

Comment: @Stuart , thanks I'll create a minimal project and see if I still observe the issue. When I hover over the squiggles it tells me the warning from the subject line; `'Function definition for 'XYZ' not found'` and suggests only two possible fixes:
`Create definition of 'XYZ' in myAPI.cpp` or
`Copy signature of 'XYZ' to clipboard`

Comment: @user20716902, oh, you're saying that when you call the functions (e.g. XYZ("some string")) the call has a squiggle. By the way, why do you use the word "methods" for the functions in the header? C doesn't have methods. Is this C++? Are the function inside a class?

Comment: @Stuart, The squiggles appear in the header only. Sorry I've been saying "methods", but meant "functions", I've fixed the question.